# В каком формате получать данные на сервере JAVA

Tags: java, iphone, mobile-development

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста. Нужно сделать сервер со Spring'ом. 
Это моб приложение. А вопрос собственно в том, в каком формате я получаю на сервере данные? Вот к примеру. Если я телефонного приложения пытаюсь зарегистрироваться в сервисе. В каком формате я отправляю с приложения и в каком формате получаю на сервере данные. 
Под моб устройством имею в виду(iphone 6, S Galaxy)
Возможно это глупый вопрос, но он существует. Будьте добры, поделитесь опытом.

Comment: Чаще всего применяется [REST](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST) и [JSON](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON).

Comment: Сергей, не сильно знаком я с РЕСТ. А можете небольшой пример пример привести?

Comment: Почему именно Spring?

Comment: Отправлять данные нужно в формате `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` как и в обычной HTML форме с методом POST.

Comment: В каком формате отправляете, в таком и получаете на сервере.

Comment: Такие требования по проекту.) Благодарю за ответы, черпнул полезную информацию. 

Добра добрым!